# Choosing the right decimation number

Tags: decimation

I am a hamradio hobbyist with little knowledge in SP.  I have to decimate the sampling rate of the received FM signal so I can get to the sampling rate that is supported by the sound card of my computer.

In the manual it says that I can choose the decimation number by dividing the initial sampling rate by bandwidth.Is this a general formula that I can always use? I tried google but could not find this specific formula.
Thank you

Comment: What is the initial sampling rate of the A/D converter you are using and what is the sampling rate that is supported by the sound card on your computer?

Comment: 1 million to 48 k of the sound card

Comment: Can you change your input sampling rate to an integer multiple of the sound card sampling rate? If so, then yes, you can throw away samples (for example to reduce the sampling rate by a factor of 10, you would simply select every 10th sample)- you just want to be careful that the signal does not have any high frequency components in it above your final sampling rate, as these would effectively fold in when you do your decimation. A low pass filter prior to he decimator is common to include for this purpose.